# Trying to enlist the arguments of a method with the values

Tags: java, methods, reflection, parameters, instrumentation

I want to save the values and types of arguments passed to a method.

This is a requirement of a bigger project that I am doing. So, presently I need to save the values and types of arguments, in the order they are declared in method signature, right at the first line of method body. However, I will not know the number of arguments. **Hence I am looking for a JAVA technique that enlists all its method parameters with their corresponding value.**

The number of arguments can be very large and the names of arguments wouldn't be known.

If this cannot happen directly, any suggestion towards how this could be done will be helpful.

```
public void stay(String temp1, int temp2, double temp3){

    //**--code to save the values of temp1, temp2, temp3 somehow--**

    //method body that will change the value of parameters
}
```

EDIT 1:
The `stay` method mentioned above can be anything and I cannot explicitly change its code. I am using instrumentation to add few lines of code in the method body. In that way, I want to add certain segment of code in the method body(logically at the beginning) which saves the values of parameters. Saving can happen in JSON format. Their types can be known by using javassist. But bottleneck is to know the values of parameters.

Putting it other way:
What will you do if you want to store the values of parameters of a method in a list(which is declared inside the method)? Since parameters can be large in number, we can't really hard code the process. 
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "save" or "enlist" exactly? Can you not just store them in class-level variables?

Comment: I want to save the values of parameters before they get changed in method body. I want to store the values of parameters in a list, so that, if I want to re-call the method sometime in future, i know the types of argument in a specified order and their saved value, I can call the method without needing to reach the program at the point where method was called. Even for storing them in a class level variable, I will have to know the count of  parameters and what are their names.

Did I make myself clear?

Comment: How will you not know what the count of params is, as the number and type of params for a method is set at compile time?  And what about objects passed as parameters?  Will you need to store them in their original state?

Comment: So basically the method under consideration will be coming from an entirely different source. My program is supposed to debug it, if needed. I mistakenly mentioned that count will not be known. I can know the count using reflection. My bad there.
However, I want to save the values of the those parameters. If they are not primitive type, they will be serialized. 
There are certain parameters that  are passed to the method(primitive and non primitive), those are needed to be saved(or serialized as a JSON object) as the first step of method body.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question, but I guess I have an answer for you.

Did you want to call a function with unknown types of parameters?

Implement your class as below:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someFuntion(Object... objects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            Object object = objects[i];
            if(object != null)
                System.out.println("Argument " + i + ": " + object.toString() + " (" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + ")");
            else
                System.out.println("Argument " + i + ": null");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, call this class with:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.someFuntion("test", 8, new SomeClass());
```

The output will be:

> Argument 0: test (String)
>
> Argument 1: 8 (Integer)
>
> Argument 2: app.SomeClass@55f96302 (SomeClass)

Hope it helps you!

**EDIT**: if you want to serialize the result as a JSON structure, you can store it as a JSON array, for example.

**EDIT2**: Or replace your stay method to:

```
public void stay(Object... objects)
```

and now your parameters of stay method are available on *objects* array within the stay method.

Comment: This is towards where I want to reach. I thought of similar step. However, what I want is :
`someClass.someFuntion("test", 8, new SomeClass());`
This should be passed with parameters of the my specified method
`someClass.someFuntion(temp1, temp2,temp3)`
where temp1, temp2, temp3 are the parameters of `stay` method.

Comment: Thank you for showing patience. However, there is this constraint (mentioned in comments to question as well), that I can't change the code of `stay`. I have made an attempt to make the question more clear, kindly go through it once, I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you call _stay_ method in **your** (editable) code? If yes, just store parameters before the call of the method. Otherwise, take a look on [Java reflection documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).